# Make List(Of T) a Property

Tags: vb.net, properties

I'm trying to make a Property for a `List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, sVolumeInfo))` variable. So far I've got:

```
Public ReadOnly Property RemoveableDrives As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, sVolumeInfo))
    Get
        RemoveableDrives = mRemoveableDrives
    End Get
End Property
Private mRemovableDrives As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, sVolumeInfo))

Public Sub New()
    mRemoveableDrives = New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, sVolumeInfo))
End Sub
```

My problem is, is that the `= mRemoveableDrives` does not compile, VB.NET insists on changing mRemoveableDrives to the Class name.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: The `mRemovableDrives` variable is spelled without an "e" when it's declared, but then you spell it with an "e" (e.g. "mRemov**e**ableDrives") when you use it.  Is that the problem, or is that just a typo that got introduced when you posted the question?

Comment: That's just a typo.  I've got Option Strict switched on...

Answer (score 1):

Don’t use assignment to the function name, use `Return`.

```
Get
    Return mRemoveableDrives
End Get
```

That said, it’s almost certainly a bad idea to expose a collection member nilly-willy to the outside for read and write access.

Comment: I tried "Return" with the same compiler compliant.

I'm now using a Function to return the Collection, the compiler doesn't seem to mind that...